# How to make the updated value in factory to be shown in DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-factory

Please look at the example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lk2w59czGEsqVMdNhWVj?p=preview). I want the dom to updated after each second.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);
myApp.factory("productCountFactory", function() {
  var total = 0
  setInterval(function checkItems(){
            total++;
        }, 1000);

    var add =function(){
      total++
    }
  return {
    totalProducts: function(){
      return total
    },
    add: add
  };
});
```

Currently it updates only when I click on add button.

This is just an example. What I want to achieve is, after timeout, I want to remove certain elements from an array and display remaining values using ng-repeat. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will achieve this when using the [**$interval service**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) instead the native `setInterval()`

```js
// Code goes here

var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);
myApp.factory("productCountFactory", function($interval) {
  var total = 0
  $interval(function checkItems() {
    total++;
  }, 1000);

  var add = function() {
    total++
  }
  return {
    totalProducts: function() {
      return total
    },
    add: add
  };
});
myApp.controller("welcomeContoller", function($scope, productCountFactory) {
  $scope.productCountFactory = productCountFactory;
});

myApp.controller("productController", function($scope, productCountFactory) {
  $scope.addProduct = function() {
    console.log(productCountFactory.totalProducts());
    productCountFactory.add();
    console.log(productCountFactory.totalProducts());
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="ui-bootstrap@*" data-semver="1.1.1" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-1.1.1.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="welcomeContoller">
    {{productCountFactory.totalProducts()}}
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div ng-controller="productController">
    <div class="addRemoveCart">
      <button ng-click="removeProduct()">Remove</button>
      <button ng-click="addProduct(1)">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

But note that:

> *[source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval#overview)*
>
> Intervals created by this service must be **explicitly destroyed when
>   you are finished with them**. In particular they are not automatically
>   destroyed when a controller's scope or a directive's element are
>   destroyed. You should take this into consideration and make sure to
>   always cancel the interval at the appropriate moment.

You can make sure that the interval is destroyed with something like:

```
var myInterval = $interval(someFunction);

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    if (angular.isDefined(myInterval)) {
        $interval.cancel(myInterval);
        myInterval = undefined;
    }
});
```